# How can prepend a currency to javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a currency symbol "EUR" before the product price in this variable:

```
  var items = [];
  var checkoutProducts = {{DL - Checkout Products}} || [];

  items = checkoutProducts.slice().map(function(product){
    return {
        id: product.id,
        price: parseFloat(product.price),
        quantity: product.quantity
    };
  });

  return items;
}
```

This function is for Google Tag Manager and the DataLayer Variable.
Thanks.

Comment: `.slice()` is not required

Comment: `'EUR' + product.price`…?

Comment: Please mention the sample objects and the desired output as well.

Comment: do you need the price property in the returned object to be a `NUMBER` or it can be a `STRING` ?

Comment: Your code is about the 'model' concepts but your question is about the 'ui'. You'll need to format somehow further in the process but we cannot help you further because we don't know your 'ui' part.